# How to convert elastic timestamp json into a c# timestamp

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

at a request from elastic I get a json with a timestamp in json format.
But I would like to get it in a C# DateTime format / object.
**How can I convert json timestamp into C# DateTime**?

Frank

what I get now:

> { "timestamp": "{\r\n  \"month\": 3,\r\n  \"hour\": 21,\r\n  \"nanosecond\": 0,\r\n  \"year\": 2019,\r\n  \"isNull\": false,\r\n  \"millisecond\": 0.0,\r\n  \"value\": \"2019-03-02T21:22:29\",\r\n  \"day\": 2,\r\n  \"binData\": \"eHcDAhYXHgAAAAA=\",\r\n  \"minute\": 22,\r\n  \"second\": 29\r\n}",

what I would like to have:

> "2/3/2019 21:22:29 PM"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can try like this using JSON.NET:**

---

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string data = @"{
        'timestamp': {
            'month': 3,
            'hour': 21,
            'nanosecond': 0,
            'year': 2019,
            'isNull': false,
            'millisecond': 0,
            'value': '2019-03-02T21:22:29',
            'day': 2,
            'binData': 'eHcDAhYXHgAAAAA=',
            'minute': 22,
            'second': 29
        }
    }";

    JObject elasticDateObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(data);
    DateTime resolvedDate = DateTime.Parse(elasticDateObject["timestamp"]["value"].ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(resolvedDate.ToString(@"yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss tt", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US")));
}
```

---

**Outputting:**

```
2019/03/02 09:22:29 PM
```

Comment: Thanks Kunal! 
In my case I changed one line to

string myElasticDate = elasticDateObject["value"].ToString();

and it works fine! :-)